# How do I get a ESM module using the Async ESM import

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I have the following code in a plunker...

```
// Thing.js
export class Thing{
  constructor(){
    console.log("This thing is alive!!!!");
  }
}
// index
import("./Thing.js").then(
  (Thing)=>{
      new Thing();
  }
)
```

But what I get is

> VM662 script.js:5 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Thing is not a constructor

[?](https://plnkr.co/edit/JSwhIvTSo1h77uqVUK1k)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to read Thing as if it were a default export rather than a named export. Either of these will work:

```
// Thing.js
export class Thing{
  constructor(){
    console.log("This thing is alive!!!!");
  }
}
// index
import("./Thing.js").then(
  ({Thing})=>{ // NOTE destructuring since Thing is a named export
      new Thing();
  }
)
```

or this

```
// Thing.js
export default class Thing{ // NOTE default
  constructor(){
    console.log("This thing is alive!!!!");
  }
}
// index
import("./Thing.js").then(
  (Thing)=>{ // No destructuring needed, can read Thing directly
      new Thing();
  }
)
```

Comment: To add here is the example I got to work https://plnkr.co/edit/JPRuHMNHPuQODRR6fFe5?p=preview